# Handle multiple async sources of data with priority to improve First Contentful Paint

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I already found a solution, but I don't know if it's the best practice or not. Imagine that for a component in React, I need to fetch datas coming from external source. One source `fetchSlow` sends complete data but is slow, the other `fetchFast` sends partial data but is fast

The idea is to make both calls in parallel and apply the following rule:

- If `fetchFast` is faster, render the component partially and re-render with complete data from `fetchSlow`
- If `fetchSlow` is faster, ignore `fetchFast`

The purpose is to improve the time before the first render (as `fetchSlow` could be really slow sometimes)

My solution is the following, by using a variable `allDataFetched` to ignore or not the update of data

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState({ data1: null, data2: null });

useEffect( ()=>{
  let allDataFetched = false;

  // fetchFast is fast but only provide data1
  fetchFast().then((res) => {
    if (allDataFetched === false) {
      const tmpData = { ...data, ...result.data };
      setData(tmpData);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  });

  // fetchSlow is slow but  provide data1 and data2
  fetchSlow().then((res) => {
    setData(res.data);
    setLoading(false);
    allDataFetched = true;
  })},[]);

  if (!loading) {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{data.data1 === null ? "loading" : data.data1}</div>
        <div>{data.data2 === null ? "loading" : data.data2}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return <p>Load</p>;
};
```

But it seems to be a weird solution, is there a way to do it better? Unfortunately I didn't find a lot of topics about handling multiple data sources at the same time with priority.

Comment: You can do that, it's okay-ish, but really you need to make your fetch calls from an effect, not during every render!

Comment: Ah yes, my bad, this is what I do, but I try to simplify the example (and forget to put the useEffect) - Corrected now